# Possible to 'catch' an error in a SQL udf?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery mentions that you cannot use the `SAFE.` prefix on udf's: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-reference#safe_prefix. Is there a way then to catch an error in a udf? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do (in shorthand):

```
function fast_in(elem, array_of_elem) AS (
    (SELECT elem in array_of_elem)
)

function fallback_in(elem, array_of_elem) AS (
    my_long_custom_in_function
)
```

The first one would work for something like:

```
SELECT fast_in(1, [1,2])
--> SELECT (SELECT 1 IN UNNEST([1,2]))
```

And the second one would work for something where equality is not supported, such as:

```
SELECT fallback_in(json '1', [json '1', json '2'])
```

And so I'd like to run the actual query as something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SAFE.fast_in(x, xs), fallback_in(x, xs))
```

But of course BigQuery doesn't support that as far as I can tell (it seems the scripting in BigQuery is the most limited I've even run across, even worse than vimscript).

Comment: Perhaps you have an XY problem? Why is a UDF throwing an error in the first place?

Comment: @MitchWheat it should throw an error, the udf is `x IN UNNEST(xs)`, and if the input data type is one of json, array, geography, or struct (for strict equality), it won't work. For any other type it will work. This is built-in and so much faster than the custom JS function (500 lines of code) to do an equality check, so I'd much rather use that one for the 85% of types that support it.

Comment: `SAFE.` prefixed function **catches** runtime error, I think.  But in your case of `x IN UNNEST(xs)` for **json** type, it will generate a compile-time error which can't be captured in runtime.

Comment: @Jaytiger I see. Does BQ have any mechanism to deal with this, or the only way is using dynamic/constructed SQL outside BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, it is not feasible to catch errors directly in standard SQL UDFs in `BigQuery`, but, one possible solution could be to return a structure from the `UDF` that encompasses the output and a related error message (if any).

let me show you how:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION my_udf(input INT64)
RETURNS STRUCT<result INT64, error STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    // your UDF logic here
    return {result: input * 2, error: null};
  } catch (e) {
    return {result: null, error: e.message};
  }
""";

SELECT my_udf(10).result, my_udf(10).error;
```

as you see,the UDF returns a struct that includes both the result of the calculation and an error message (if any).

**Update :**
I think we can also use a `CASE` statement within the `UDF` to handle different cases and return appropriate values

something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_udf(input INT64)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  switch (input) {
    case 1:
      return 100;
    case 2:
      return 200;
    default:
      return null;
  }
""";
```

and if the `UDF` returns null,we can use a `COALESCE` statement to handle the null value like this :

```
SELECT COALESCE(my_udf(x), fallback_value) FROM my_table;
```

and about your comment, it is important to have proper error handling and bubbling up of exceptions in each `UDF` and I think,it may be helpful to test `UDFs` in isolation before using them in more complex queries to ensure that they are properly handling exceptions!

for example :

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION my_udf(input INT64)
RETURNS STRUCT<result INT64, error STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    // your_UDF_logic
    if (input < 0) {
      throw new Error('Input must be a positive integer.');
    }
    return {result: input * 2, error: null};
  } catch (e) {
    return {result: null, error: e.message};
  }
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION my_udf2(input INT64)
RETURNS STRUCT<result INT64, error STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    const intermediateResult = my_udf(input);
    if (intermediateResult.error) {
      throw new Error(intermediateResult.error);
    }
    return {result: intermediateResult.result + 10, error: null};
  } catch (e) {
    return {result: null, error: e.message};
  }
""";

SELECT my_udf(-5).result, my_udf(-5).error;
-- result: null, 'entry data must be a positive integer.'

SELECT my_udf(10).result, my_udf(10).error;
-- result: 20, null
    
SELECT my_udf2(10).result, my_udf2(10).error;
-- result: 30, null

SELECT my_udf2(-5).result, my_udf2(-5).error;
-- result: null, 'entry data must be a positive integer.'
```

as you can see,`my_udf` throws an error if the input is negative, and the error message is returned in the `error` field of the output struct and `my_udf2` calls `my_udf` and verifies if an error was returned, of course if there was an error, `my_udf2` throws a new error with the same message!

good luck!

Comment: this is a good idea and thanks for this consideration. One of the tricky things then is bubbling up exceptions...For example, maybe `SELECT my_udf(col) FROM tbl` works well, but what about `SELECT my_udf2(my_udf1(col)) FROM tbl`. But anyways, I think this is the best approach thus far.

Comment: apologies, this should've been the accepted answer, but StackOverflow auto-awarded the bounty. Sorry about that.

Comment: @David542 I don't really care much about it, but since this issue needs to be addressed eventually, I would appreciate it if you could inform the website support team so that they can prevent such incidents from happening in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the behavior you are trying to replicate is to execute one function and if it fails then execute the other, you could use the `BEGIN...EXCEPTION` [block](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#beginexceptionend) to do so, e.g.:

```sql
BEGIN
  SELECT fast_in(x, xs);
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT fallback_in(x, xs);
END;
```

Comment: Ok sure, but how would I call that in a query? Pretend that there are 100M rows in a query and I want to use a UDF for that? How does using scripting help for that?

Answer (score -1):

SAFE_CAST can be used for handling casting type errors but it wouldn't be sufficient for catching any errors from UDF. I think you need to have separate exception handling block in your code itself.
Many Thanks.